# how to convert .DBF file format to .dbf file format?

Tags: database, foxpro, dbf, dbase

I want to acccess dBase database. It's not directly have any database name. it's have table name base data file. Normally dBase file format open in msaccess & msexcel. But it have .DBF file extension, so it's not opened in msaccess or msexcel. So i want to convert .DBF file to .dbf file format. Otherwise how can I get the database name? Because the data should be entered via foxpro. I don't have any coding - I only access the database file.

Comment: A `.DBF` file is the same as a `.dbf` file. There's no difference just because the extensions are differently cased. Your question makes no sense at all. What exactly is the problem with opening the database file? What error are you getting? What exact software are you using (Access 2007, Excel XP, or something else)? You need to provide much more detail, because what you've written here isn't meaningful. You should edit your post to provide *much* more information.

Answer (score 3):

Typically .DBF file extensions are for dBASE or FoxPro (or Visual Foxpro too).

If you are trying to access via something .Net (C#, VB, etc), Microsoft has an OleDB provider you can download and use.

The connection string will typically point to the PATH where the .dbf files are located, then your queries can just reference the table names directly (without the explicit .dbf suffixing required).

There's plenty of other answers out on using OleDB, Visual Foxpro, ConnectionStrings and creating (parameterized) queries.

Answer (score 1):

Basically an **Xbase**  *database* is a collection of three different types of files:

`xxx.dbf` Data files

`xxx.dbt` Memo files (i.e. a separate file containing full text  fields)

`xxx.ndx`  Index files pointing to a field in the relevant xxx.dbf

Unlike most other databases this collection is not combined into a single entity(database)  name.

`xxx.DBF` and  `xxx.dbf` are the same with xxx being the name of the table.